# Trying to get a return of 2 boolean values Java

Tags: java

Basically, I have two boolean values, called 'higher and same' and I want both of them to be returned in my, isNextCardHigher method

```
class HigherSame{
    boolean higher = false;
    boolean same = false;
    boolean[] HandS = {higher, same};
}


boolean isNextCardHigher(TCard lastCard, TCard nextCard, HigherSame highersame, boolean HandS[] ){

    if (nextCard.rank == lastCard.rank){//Higher = game over
        boolean same, higher;

        if(nextCard.rank == lastCard.rank){
            same = true;
        }

        if (nextCard.rank > lastCard.rank){
            higher = true;
        }
        return HandS[];
```

Comment: It appears we have an angry down-voter here.

Comment: Yes, some explanations would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

You could change the return type for an object of the class HigherSame, this way you have both your booleans.

Answer (score 1):

You might change the return type from `boolean` to `boolean[]`, but I would probably favor returning an instance of `HigherSame`.

Answer (score 0):

A `boolean` value has two states (`true` and `false`). You are essentially trying to return 3 states (higher, same, or neither). I suggest using a more appropriate data type. For example, you could use an enum:

```
enum CardRelation { HIGHER, SAME, LOWER };
```

Or you could return a `HigherSame`.

You could also take a comparator-style approach and return an `int`: negative if less than, 0 if equal, 1 if higher -- then `>= 0` can be used to test if the result is "same or higher". You could even implement `Comparable` or use a proper `Comparator`. While `int` itself carries no meaning, this style of comparison is frequently used in Java and so the meaning can remain clear.

Think of what you are trying to determine (compare two cards) and try to come up with a data type that naturally reflects that concept and keeps appropriate semantics.

A `boolean[]`, by the way, also loses all semantic value and is generally a poor choice, "result[0]" requires some explanation and you also end up making assumptions about the array length all over the place, and what does a `null` signify?

Answer (score -2):

A method can only return 1 object or value. If you want to return multiple objects or values, you can return an array or list. In your case if you have a method like this

```
boolean isNextCardHigher() { ... }
```

you can change that to return an array of boolean values.

```
boolean[] isNextCardHigher() { ... }
```

Then inside your method you would create an array, fill it with the values you want, and return the whole array.

```
boolean[] result = new boolean[2];
result[0] = same;
result[1] = higher;
return result;
```

Comment: You could do this, but it is very unclear in usage later ("result[0]" does not really self-document as "same"). It would make more sense to use a data type that wasn't a `boolean` and that clearly represented the problem, since it takes more than `true` or `false` to represent the result.

Comment: I totally agree, I just wanted to try a solution that was close to what the OP already had.